# Get the number of bytes available in socket by 'recv' with 'MSG_PEEK' in C++

Tags: c, sockets, buffer, recv, peek

C++ has the following function to receive bytes from socket, it can check for number of bytes available with the `MSG_PEEK` flag. With `MSG_PEEK`, the returned value of 'recv' is the number of bytes available in socket:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
ssize_t recv(int socket, void *buffer, size_t length, int flags);
```

I need to get the number of bytes available in the socket without creating `buffer` (without allocating memory for `buffer`). Is it possible and how?

Comment: note:  the flag does *not only* return the number of bytes available. `MSG_PEEK` actually **copies data** into the given buffer!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're looking for is `ioctl(fd,FIONREAD,&bytes_available)` , and under windows `ioctlsocket(socket,FIONREAD,&bytes_available)`.

Be warned though, the OS doesn't necessarily guarantee how much data it will buffer for you, so if you are waiting for very much data you are going to be better off reading in data as it comes in and storing it in your own buffer until you have everything you need to process something.

To do this, what is normally done is you simply read chunks at a time, such as

```
char buf[4096];
ssize_t bytes_read;
do {
     bytes_read = recv(socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
     if (bytes_read > 0) {
         /* do something with buf, such as append it to a larger buffer or
          * process it */
     }
} while (bytes_read > 0);
```

And if you don't want to sit there waiting for data, you should look into `select` or `epoll` to determine when data is ready to be read or not, and the `O_NONBLOCK` flag for sockets is very handy if you want to ensure you never block on a recv.

Comment: the incoming data to socket is supposed to be "ongoing stream of bytes" or a "series of tcp packages"?

Comment: peeking with maximum number of bytes (handle-able by programme) will make a double job i think, coz when we actually deal with the data, we read the second time

Comment: Correct, which is why the first method is preferable, although unless you are operating at Gbps speeds then you'll never notice it..

Comment: Incoming data will trickle in. If the packets sent by the other end are small, they'll more than likely appear all at once, but it's by no means a guarantee. So it's an ongoing stream of bytes from your perspective as the reciever, and it's up to you to know when you've received all the bytes you are expecting.

Comment: You *can* know how much data is immediately available, which is what he is asking about. There aren't many valid uses of this information, but it does exist.

Comment: Note that when using UDP, i.e. SOCK_DGRAM, you should read the send  message at once as partial reads will discard the excess length; so in that case ioctl FIONREAD seems the way to go.

Comment: @KlamerSchutte On SOCK_DGRAM you can use MSG_PEEK | MSG_TRUNK. Peek means the data is not discarded and trunk means the actual size of the message is returned even if larger than the buffer. Then simply pass in a 1 byte buffer and ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you can use the [`ioctlsocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573.aspx) function with the `FIONREAD` flag to ask the socket how many bytes are available without needing to read/peek the actual bytes themselves.  The value returned is the minimum number of bytes `recv()` can return without blocking.  By the time you actually call `recv()`, more bytes may have arrived.

Comment: This answer is flat out wrong. It's quite clear in the documentation that `FIONREAD`, on Windows, does *not* return the number of bytes that are available from `recv` without blocking. On Windows, `recv` can pull data from lower layers (such as filters and queues with their own buffers) while `FIONREAD` does not do so and only checks the top layer. See [item 12](https://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/lame-list.html).

Comment: Imagine if the data goes through a filter when `recv` is called and the filter has no reversal capability. How can `FIONREAD` possibly tell how many bytes `recv` could read without invoking that filter? And how can it invoke the filter if the filter has no reversal capability? This *cannot* work on Windows. (Worse, it *may* work when you try it because your system may not happen to have such a driver loaded. But when your code runs on other people's computers ... boom.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: [per MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573.aspx): "*FIONREAD: Use to determine **the amount of data pending in the network's input buffer** that can be read from socket `s`... **`FIONREAD` returns the amount of data that can be read in a single call to the `recv` function**, which may not be the same as the total amount of data queued on the socket.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sadly, that's incorrect for the reasons I explained in my two comments. The `FIONREAD` call cannot do anything that is irreversible while `recv` can. So it may return a smaller number. Microsoft support of non-native socket operations is spotty in many ways and this is one of them. This is why it is highly recommended that software meant to run on Windows use the Windows APIs, not the ones meant to be POSIXy.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I don't know anything about network filters, bu if you are reading the data anyway, what does it matter if it goes through a filter or not? The data is going in one direction and ends up in the socket's input buffer. I don't see why reversal logic is a limiting factor, unless maybe if `recv()` is being called with `MSG_PEEK`, but that is not common, and besides I would expect that to read the data through the filter and store it in the buffer anyway, and then just peek the buffer and leave the data there for a later non-peek read to remove it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Consider a compress/expand filter: Say fifty bytes are received from the socket in some compressed format and that each of them expand to enough data to fill the buffer that `recv` pulls from. So 49 of those bytes are still in some low-level buffer and the buffer `recv` pulls from is full. How can `FIONREAD` know how many bytes `recv` would return? It is impossible. The filter can't know what the later bytes expand to without expanding the earlier ones. While `recv` will refill the buffer when it's empty. This really does happen on Windows.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: if one compressed byte expands to fill the entire input buffer, I don't see why `FIONREAD` would not simply return the input buffer size. I don't expect it to account for later bytes until after the socket has to go back to the low level to read more data and it decompresses the next byte into the input buffer. `recv()` will not block if the input buffer has any final bytes in it, unless `MSG_WAITALL` is used

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, exactly. While `recv` will be able to get all the bytes because as soon as the buffer is empty (copied into the buffer the user supplies in the call to `recv`), it attempts to refill it from lower layers. Thus `FIONREAD` *cannot* return as many bytes as `recv` might be able to because it cannot do anything irreversible like invoking the filter. So `FIOREAD` will return the X bytes in the highest level buffer, `recv` could return up to 50*X bytes by invoking the filter to refill the buffer from the received bytes in a lower-level buffer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132854/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-david-schwartz).

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when using `FIONREAD`! The problem with using `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &available)` is that it will always return the total number of bytes available for reading in the socket buffer on some systems.

This is no problem for STREAM sockets (TCP) but misleading for DATAGRAM sockets (UDP). As for datagram sockets read requests are capped to the size of the first datagram in the buffer and when reading less than she size of the first datagram, all unread bytes of that datagram are still discarded. So ideally you want to know only the size of the next datagram in the buffer.

E.g. on macOS/iOS [it is documented](https://manpagez.com/man/2/getsockopt/) that `FIONREAD` always returns the total amount (see comments about `SO_NREAD`). To only get the size of the next datagram (and total size for stream sockets), you can use the code below:

```
int available;
socklen_t optlen = sizeof(readable);
int err = getsockopt(soc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NREAD, &available, &optlen);
```

On Linux `FIONREAD` is documented to [only return the size of the next datagram](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html) for UDP sockets.

On Windows `ioctlsocket(socket, FIONREAD, &available)` is documented to always give the total size:

> If the socket passed in the s parameter is message oriented (for example, type SOCK_DGRAM), FIONREAD returns the reports the total number of bytes available to read, **not the size of the first datagram (message) queued on the socket.**

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2spi/nc-ws2spi-lpwspioctl

I am unaware of a way how to get the size of the first datagram only on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: this cannot be done with MS-Windows WinSock2,
as I can discovered over the last week of trying.

Glad to have finally found this post, which sheds some light on the issues I've been having, using latest Windows 10 Pro, version 20H2 Build 19042.867 (x86/x86_64) :

On a bound, disconnected UDP socket `sk` (in Listening / Server mode):

1. Any attempt to use either `ioctlsocket(sk, FIONREAD, &n_bytes)`
   OR `WsaIoctl` with a shifted `FIONREAD` argument, though they succeed,
   and retern 0, after a call to `select` returns > with that
   `sk` FD bit set in the read FD set,
   and the ioctl call returns 0 (success), and n_bytes is > 0,
   causes the socket `sk` to be in a state where any
   subsequent call to recv(), recvfrom(), or ReadFile() returns
   `SOCKET_ERROR` with a WSAGetLastError() of 10045 "Operation Not Supported" or ReadFile error 87 "Invalid Parameter".

Moreover, even worse:

2. Any attempt to use recv or recvfrom with the `MSG_PEEK` msg_flags
   parameter returns -1 and WSAGetLastError returns 10040 'A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself'.

Yet for that socket I *did* successfully call:

```
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, bufsz = 4096, sizeof(bufsz))
```

and the UDP packet being received was only 120 bytes in size.

In short, with modern windows winsock2 (winsock2.h / Ws2_32.dll),
there appears to be absolutely no way to use any documented API
to determine the number of bytes received on a bound UDP socket
before calling recv() / recvfrom() in MSG_WAITALL blocking mode to
actually receive the whole packet.

If you do not call ioctlsocket() or WsaIoctl or
`recv{,from}(...,MSG_PEEK,...)`
before entering `recv{,from}(...,MSG_WAITALL,...)`,
then the `recv{,from}` succeeds.

I am considering advising clients that they must install and run
a Linux instance with MS Services for Linux under their windows
installation, and developing some
API to communicate with it from Windows, so that reliable
asynchronous UDP communication can be achieved - or does anyone
know of a good open source replacement for WinSock2?

I need access to a "C" library TCP+UDP/IP implementation for
modern Windows 10 that conforms to its own documentation,
unlike WinSock2 -  does anyone know of one?

Comment: Please can you format your answer a bit better; I find it hard to read it