# Determine amount of available bytes in socket

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu, boost, boost-asio

I have a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` and want to determine if the socket contains data which is available to read. I read about `available()`, however that function sometimes also returns `0` if there is data available (in case it can be read without blocking). The executable is running on Ubuntu - maybe a system call could help?

Comment: If no data is available for a read I would continue and check back later. I know async_read would solve that too, but I already have a big polling loop so it would be perfect if there was a simple way of checking the available bytes.

Comment: At the downvoter: Why did you downvote? Can I add any more important information?

Comment: As you said, I all I need to know if a socket contains readable data. Is there a function to do that?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/12984816/1741542 answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just need to know whether the socket contains readable data, just issue your regular non-blocking `read` from the socket. If there is data, you need to read it anyway, so just attempt the read.

If you're trying to avoid the expense of a `read` if there's nothing to read, realize that you're just adding an extra operation. Checking if there's data to read is not significantly cheaper than attempting to read.

Of course, just having a pending `async_read` is better. This lets Boost's reactor do its job.